Rider IDE - Project Specific Theme
I am trying out Rider IDE, and was wondering if there was a way to set per-project themes, or say different color-scheme for backend and frontend to be able to quickly see which of the two I have clicked on.
Changing theme seems to affect both/all open instances of Rider.
The specific theme does not matter, I would only like to get a nice and clear visual difference between my frontend and backend projects.
Rider has this 'project color' option, but that only applies to the logo of the project at the top left, and it too subtle for what I want.


As far as I know, in JetBrains Rider, it's not currently possible to apply different color schemes or themes per project directly.

If any body has a workaround, I'll hear it :) Otherwise @liaifat85 you could post your comment as an answer (with version of Rider) and I would accept that ;)

It's a restriction of IntelliJ-based IDE. You can vote the corresponding YouTrack issue here:
IJPL-49383 IDE Appearance : Customize per project

As of Rider:
Version: 2024.2.6
Build: 242.23339.62
9 October 2024
It does not seem to be possible to have per project theming.
